# Require help for SWT DateTime in Java

Tags: java, datetime, swt

I retrieve a `Date` from the database using the `ResultSet` `rsExpid`.

```
Date joindate = rsExpid.getDate("join_date_ad");
System.out.println(joindate);
int year = joindate.getYear();
System.out.println(year);
int month =joindate.getMonth();
System.out.println(month);
int day = joindate.getDay();
System.out.println(day);
dateTimeJoin4.setDate(year, month, day);
```

When I print `joindate` to the console it shows correctly as `2011-08-03`, but when I print the `year` to the console I was amazed to see `111`.  Similarly printing the month produced `7` and the day resulted in `3`.

The variable `dateTimeJoin4` is my SWT `DateTime`. It is not setting any value and it is also not giving any error message. Could please anybody help me on this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Chances are you haven't read the documentation for [`Date.getYear`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getYear%28%29) and [`Date.getMonth`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getMonth%28%29):

> Returns a value that is the result of subtracting 1900 from the year that contains or begins with the instant in time represented by this Date object, as interpreted in the local time zone.

and

> Returns a number representing the month that contains or begins with the instant in time represented by this Date object. The value returned is between 0 and 11, with the value 0 representing January.

respectively. Likewise [`Date.getDay`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getDay%28%29) returns the day of the week, not the day of the month - you want [`Date.getDate()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getDate%28%29) for that (or preferrably a different API entirely, either `Calendar` or Joda Time).

This has nothing to do with SWT's `DateTime` type - after all, you only use that in the last line. When something behaves unusually, your first port of call should be the documentation. SWT's `DateTime.setDate` method is documented to require a year between 1752 and 9999, so 111 will be confusing it. Admittedly it would have been nice if it had thrown an exception, but even so...

The fact that you're calling deprecated methods should have been a hint to you, although `Calendar` *also* uses 0-11 for its months.

Personally I would strongly encourage you to use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) for as much of your date and time work as you can. It's a *far* superior date and time API to the one built into Java. It's not immediately clear whether it's worth you using it here (if this is *all* you have to do) but if you're doing anything *at all* significant (including parsing, formatting or any kind of arithmetic) you should be using it.

Comment: @Dinup: Did you not notice the deprecation warnings - it's worth taking note of them. And of course checking the documentation when something goes wrong.

Comment: @jon skkeet thanks yes i noticed it but once i was working on time at that time i think it worked correctly so just want to check it.thanks for you help. u have helped me twice already

Comment: I@john i have used the Calendar.getInstance() and setting date in it.t worked correctly. is this one effective to use?

Comment: @Dinup: It will work, yes. The month is still 0-based, and it's *horrible* to use for calculations, but if you're *just* moving the data from one place to SWT DateTime, it's probably okay.

Answer (score 2):

I tried using this method and it worked correctly so this method can be useful to other.

```
Calendar startCal = Calendar.getInstance();
startCal.setTime(joindate);
int months= startCal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int years= startCal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int days= startCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
System.out.println(months+1);
System.out.println(years);
System.out.println(days);
dateTimeJoin4.setDate(years, months+1, days);
```

Answer (score 0):

getDay() return the position of the day not the date like suppose today is Monday it will return 1, it start from the sunday with 0 value.

as well as the getMonth() return the position as starting value is 0 for january at now you getting the 7 instead of 8.

for getting date you can use the SimpleDateFormat or DateFormat by passing the format string in that you can get it

example links

http://www.roseindia.net/java/javadate/date-format.shtml

http://www.java-examples.com/java-simpledateformat-class-example